# How can I dynamically change ngModel value in Angular 10

Tags: angular

In Angular 10, I'm dynamically generating three dropdowns and need to dynamically generate their ngModel values (e.g., row1, row2, row3).

```
<table>
     <tr *ngFor="let num of [0, 1, 2]; let i=index">
       <td>
         <h4>Row {{ num + 1 }}</h4>
         <select matNativeControl [(ngModel)]="row[num+1]">
             <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">{{ item.fruit }}</option>
           </select>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

`(ngModel)]="row[num+1]"` is where I'm trying to add a 1, 2, 3 as the dropdowns multiply. The  header is dynamically changing but ngModel is not and is throwing an error as it is finding `row` to be undefined. I've tried several different ways and have hit a wall.

Here is code from app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  row: any;
  row1: any;
  row2: any;
  row3: any;
  items: any;
  num: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items = [
      { fruit: 'apple', color: 'red' },
      { fruit: 'orange', color: 'orange' },
      { fruit: 'grape', color: 'purple' }
    ];
  }

  // printVal() {
  //   console.log('Test: ', this.row[this.num].fruit);
  // }
}
```

Here is stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9wr3vh

Answer (score 0):

row[num] isn't equal to row1. It is searching a variable called row,then it's  index. since you're row is undefined, it is impossible to attach ngModel to it. try something like this,

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  row = [0,1,2]
  items: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items = [
      { fruit: 'apple', color: 'red' },
      { fruit: 'orange', color: 'orange' },
      { fruit: 'grape', color: 'purple' }
    ];
  }

  // printVal() {
  //   console.log('Test: ', this.row[this.num].fruit);
  // }
}
```

And if you're trying to change items, color or fruit -i don't know which one you're trying to change.- try this in your html

```
<table>
     <tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
       <td>
         <h4>Row {{ i + 1 }}</h4>
         <select matNativeControl [(ngModel)]="item[i].color">
             <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">{{ item.fruit }}</option>
           </select>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: This does seem to be the way to go and I am trying to get the value of the each selected dropdown. So, in my example, I would want the fruit AND it's color so I need the object. I thought that the way to grab would be via the ngModel value. Using item[i] doesn't seem to work. Sorry for leaving that part out!

Comment: I have to step away but I added ‘item’ to my component and I think that should do it. I will test when I get home and check back in case you add anything else. When I confirm it’s working, I’ll add as solved. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please update your questions so that i can understand bit clearer what you're trying to achieve ?